# Django test data persisting across multiple tests despite being TestCase

Tags: django, unit-testing, testing, django-testing, pytest-django

I have a a test case that uses `setUp` and looks like this:

```
from django.test import TestCase, Client, TransactionTestCase
...
class TestPancakeView(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

        # The Year objects are empty (none here - expected)
        print(Year.objects.all())

        # When I run these Test by itself, these are empty (expected)
        # When I run the whole file, this prints out a number of
        # Pancake objects causing these tests to fail - these objects appear
        # to be persisting from previous tests
        print(Pancake.objects.all())

        # This sets up my mock/test data
        data_setup.basic_setup(self)

        # This now prints out the expected years that data_setup creates
        print(Year.objects.all())

        # This prints all the objects that I should have 
        # But if the whole file is ran - it's printing objects
        # That were created in other tests
        print(Pancake.objects.all())

        [...tests and such...]
```

`data_setup.py` is a file that just creates all the appropriate test-data for my tests when it needs them. I'm using Factory Boy for creating test data.

When I run `TestPancakeView` by itself - my tests pass as expected.

When I run my entire `test_views.py` file, my `TestPancakeView` tests fail.

If I change it to TransactionTestCase - it still fails when I run the whole file.

I'm creating the Pancake test data like this:

```
        f.PancakeFactory.create_batch(
            2,
            flavor=blueberry,
            intensity='high'
        )
```

No other tests exhibit this behavior, they all act the same way when I run them individually or when I run them as part of the entire file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the reason for this was because my `Pancake` class was from a different application in the Django project (which was tied to a different DB table); because of that - when I was creating those objects initially - since they existed on a different test DB, they were persisting.

Solution:

Use the `tearDown` functionality for each test.

Each test now has the following:

```
def tearDown(self):
    food.Pancake.objects.all().delete()
```

This ensures that my `Pancake` objects are removed after each test - so my tests against `Pancake` specifically pass regardless of being run on their own or with the rest of the file.